# Python 3, ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing some code for my fundamentals of programming class. The assignment requires our code to read from a text file that contains several values specifically:

```
999
90
4
123
189
75
5
1732
23994
16
1
750
3600
8400
2000
```

These values will correlate to cents that we will eventually break into change using a "for" loop. Eventually, it'll look like

```
ex. The minimum amount of change for x cents is:
x dollars
x quarters
x nickel
x pennies
```

To start this whole thing off, I wrote some code for the initial expression complete with a way to pluralize the "cent" in the statement.

```
def formatplural ( value, valuetext ):
    if value == 0:
        return ""
    result =  "%d %s" % ( value, valuetext )
    if value > 1:
        result += "s"
    return result

f = open ("lab2.txt", "r")
while True:
    text = f.readline()
    text = text.rstrip()
    changein = int(text)
    if not text: break
    coinsin = formatplural(changein,"cent")
    print ("The minimum amount of change for {} is" .format(coinsin))
```

When I run the code in 'cmd' I get an error

```
The minimum amount of change for 999 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 90 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 4 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 123 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 189 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 75 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 5 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 1732 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 23994 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 16 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 1 cent is
The minimum amount of change for 750 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 3600 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 8400 cents is
The minimum amount of change for 2000 cents is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mikes\Desktop\LAB 2 FOLDER\LAB2.py", line 25, in <module>
    changein = int(text)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So I'm confused. It's doing what I want but it errors out. Also, if I don't force the input to an integer, it says my inputs are a string.

Comment: You have an empty line at the bottom of your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're getting an error is because you can't convert the last line '' to a base 10 integer. Alternatively, you could read all the lines like this:

```
with open("lab2.txt", "r") as file_:
    for line in file_:
        text = line.rstrip()
        changein = int(text)
        coinsin = formatplural(changein,"cent")
        print ("The minimum amount of change for {} is" .format(coinsin))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error states you have an empty string, yet you are trying to `int(text)` **before** you check `if not text`

Try to read your file like so

```
with open ("lab2.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if not line or len(line) == 0: break
        changein = int(line)
```

Comment: Why are you checking both `not line` and `len(line) == 0`?

Comment: Doesn't hurt, does it?

Answer (score 0):

Your are converting an empty string, try to do:

```
for text in f:
```

instead of

```
while true:
```

this loop will terminate at EOF, so no need for

```
if not text: break
```

which by the way should be placed above

```
changein = int(text)
```

and is the root cause of your problem.

The `with` statement is good practice:

```
with open ("lab2.txt", "r") as f
    for text in f:
        text = text.rstrip()
```

to allow empty or faulty lines and ignore them you can do

```
try:
    change = int(text)
catch ValueError:
    continue
```